# Elfinder - Adding custom CSS class

Tags: javascript, css, elfinder

I'm using the [Elfinder](http://elfinder.org/) filemanager. When I upload a file, it automatically detect the file extension and adding a class to the file. But it lacks in some cases for new file types.

I have tried by adding the file under 'kinds' option in js but no joy;

```
'text/htm'  : 'HTM'
```

How can I create custom css classes for new file types which are not identified.

Comment: Not familiar with Elfinder, but would it work if you wrote `text/html`?

Comment: Yes I tried with html also, no joy